# Log changes on Google Script (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to create a spreadsheet where it logs data and the changes you make on it.

For example in [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MmX-oSFLBB4EkYpzNWxkB9EfdpZqG0mdNh9bmEy7Yyk/edit#gid=544444145), I used a Google Script to do it but instead of only logging in a particular row when you change the data on `Sheet1`, it copies all the data you changed since the beginning on `Sheet 2`. I only want to log a particular row each time I make a change.

Here's my code

```
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain Yes
 * in the Include column and copies them to the Report sheet.
 */

function myFunction() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tarSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cell = srcSheet.getRange("B" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
    if (val == 'Yes') {
      
      var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":D" + i);
      
      var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
      tarSheet.insertRowAfter(tarRow);
      var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow+1) + ":D" + (tarRow+1));
      
      srcRange.copyTo(tarRange);
    }
  }
};
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var srcSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (srcSheet.getSheetName() !== 'Sheet1') { return; }
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  var cols = 4;
  
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, cols);
  var values = srcRange.getValues()[0];
  if (values[1] == 'Yes') { 
    var tarSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');     
    tarSheet.appendRow(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it only changes the first row. I want to log all data though, not just the first row.

Comment: You said you want to 'log a particular row'

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. Got lost in my translation. What I meant was I want to log I make in each and every row. Sorry!

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Thank you. It says `Cannot read property 'source' of undefined` also, do I still need to manually add the triggers or no longer needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236037/discussion-between-rudolph-musngi-and-idfurw).

Comment: It is a trigger runs automatically when you make changes. You should not run from the editor. There is also no need to create a trigger for it because its name is `onEdit`. Sorry I have corrected some lines in my code.

Comment: Still not working :( I looked at the logs it says 


```
Exception: The parameters (null,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
    at onEdit(Code:7:27)
```

Comment: I think you are not using the latest code. Please check.

Comment: Can you check the sheet? Something weird is happening when I add new rows on the member column

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get it. Please add screenshots and expected output to your question.

Comment: I don't know how to attach images but I put yes in all the member's name and it only showed 6 results. Can you access my sample sheet?

Comment: I have had look at it but I still cannot get what you want to tell. About attaching image, have a look on the bottom of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).